# throw an exception or return NULL object in C++?

Tags: c++

I have this method to find an object in a list in C++.

```
Step Config::getStep(string stepName)
{
    for(int i=0; i<_NoSteps; i++)
    {
        if(_Steps[i].getStepNameStr().compare(stepName)==0)
        {
            return _Steps[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "ERROR. No processing step found for: " << stepName << endl;
    // case 1: throw exception
    // case 2: return null
}
```

I got an error while compiling: 'not all control paths return a value' as I set it 'treated warning as error'

I would like to know how to:

1. how to throw a custom exception if there is no object found
2. how to return a NULL object in C# like:  return null

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When calling the function do you always expected it to find a value.

Comment: If it's an error to not have a processing step, but the program can continue without it, then return a special instance of `Step` that means "no step available". If not having a step is a fatal error and the program can't continue, then throwing an exception is okay.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I expect to get an exception if the step is not found.

Comment: when you wrote "return a NULL object in C# like: return null" is this C# or C++? Assuming it is C++ ... Is the signature `Step Config::getStep(string stepName)` changeable? If not it's going to get messy because there is no way to return NULL or make a 'null singleton'. So then two 'null objects' will only be equal if you add `==` operators. Can you add extra methods to Step? If not, it is going to be too horrible because IMHO the 'null object' will introduce extra, new, errors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, I want to throw a custom exception.

Comment: @gbulmer yes, I can change the getStep method. what would you think is the best?

Comment: @devn, you've answered the question yourself so why did you ask?

Comment: I agree with Joachim Pileborg's summary. If failure to match stepName breaks fundamental requirements, throw an exception. IMHO, that's unusual, but possible. People have shown how to throw exceptions. I'd normally expect a missing name in a list to be 'an expected case', so I wouldn't throw an exception. For many uses of lists, the list is checked to see if a string exists, and then it's added if the word is new. It very much depends on how the class is used. NULL is a C 'idiom' to mean not found. An alternative is a 'singleton' (search google) but that may be too complex for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either return a pointer to an object, or a reference. In C++, unlike C#, you return the object by value, therefore, the object gets copied. To return it by reference, write `Step& Config::getStep(string stepName)`.

To throw an exception, just write `throw MissingStepException();` and then handle it like this:

```
try {
    Step s = c.getStep("step");
}
catch (MissingStepException& ex) {
    // handle
}
```

You need to define `MissingStepException` class first, of course.

Choosing what to do in general: return `NULL` or throw exception depends on your logic: if missing step is a logic error or an unlikely condition, it's better to use exception, otherwise returning a `NULL` pointer would do.

Comment: Yes, i am a C# programmer. I am doing something with C++ for C++/CLI. So you mean I should use either pointer to an object (*) or reference (&) when returning from a method? and a reference is more preferable?

Comment: and might I ask why reference is more preferable than pointer?

Comment: It acts like a value (so you don't need to change the calling code),  you also don't need to `delete` it manually.

Comment: i learned a lesson today of passing the reference instead of object or pointer. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

- You can not return null object. You can return null pointer if you were working with pointers.
- In C++ you can throw virtually everything.

Like:

```
 cout << "ERROR. No processing step found for: " << stepName << endl;
 throw "There was exception, no step was found";
```

**EDIT** Allow me to add the @josefx comment to my answer, so that I do not get misunderstood. As he pointed out, even if you are allow to throw virtually everything it is not a good practice at all. You should try throwing only objects that people expect to be thrown (like exception). Here I add his example of how you do that.

```
throw std::runtime_error("There was an exception, no step was found");
```

Comment: -1 for you can throw virtually everything, while true it is never a good idea to do so.

Comment: @josefx True. Still I was trying to explain the basics (as it seems the OP is not familiar with the very basics of the language). Let him know what he can do. Then using his own brains he can choose how exactly to do it. Still thanks for at least letting me know the reason for the downvote :)

Comment: At least throw std::runtime_error("There was an exception, no step was found"), it may be personal opinion but I think throwing a string is a really bad example.

Comment: @josefx. Thank you and I hope you don't mind I added your comments to my answer (with the respective credits).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not returning a pointer, you can't return `NULL`, so, if you can't modify the function signature, you need to throw an exception.

You can do so like this:

```
struct StepNotFoundException : public std::exception
{
    std::string stepName;
    StepNotFoundException(const std::string& sn) : stepName(sn) {}
};

//....

Step Config::getStep(string stepName)
{
    for(int i=0; i<_NoSteps; i++)
    {
        if(_Steps[i].getStepNameStr().compare(stepName)==0)
        {
            return _Steps[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "ERROR. No processing step found for: " << stepName << endl;
    throw StepNotFoundException(stepName );
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::runtime_error` and pass the string to its constructor, so you get the storage for free and the `what()` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the code should throw an exception if data/conditions break your assumptions.
In this situations if you expect that getStep may not find the name I think is better to return a value then throw.

To answer your questions:

1 defining, throwing and handling an exception

```
class myException : public std::exception { ... };
try {
    ...
    throw myException();
}
catch (const std::exception &theException) {
    ...
}
```

2 It is not possible to return NULL. However if it makes sense you can return an empty value, but the calling code should handle this.

```
Step Config::getStep(string stepName)
{
    ...
    return Step(""); 
}
```